# Better way to get last modified time for Google contact using Google people API

Tags: google-people-api

I use the Java Google People API to sync Google contacts with a desktop application.  To do it, I need to get the last modified date/time for each Google contact. For that, I have been using `updateTime` in the Source field, which I get by iterating over `person.metadata.sources`.

But it sometimes returns a date/time which is more recent than the date/time of when I actually updated the contact.  And that causes the contact to get synced unnecessarily.  I wonder if Google is touching my contacts periodically in the background which updates the updateTime.  If so, is there a better way for me to get the "real" update time for a contact?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say the date/time is more recent - by how much? A few hours? Days? Months? Do you have any other application which you use which may modify any of your contacts?

Comment: The date/time is more recent by days or weeks.  No, I have no other application that modifies my contacts.

Comment: If this is really true then you should rather file a bug with Google. You can do this on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)